# Can I run windows phone virtually in PC?

Tags: windows-mobile

Is it possible to run Windows mobile or phone run virtually in PC? 
If YES; then how can I run it? Which is primary or minimum hardware & O.S. requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer tools include Hyper-V images that you can run a virtual phone within any Hyper-V capable PC.

Comment: thanks and What is Primary/ minimum requirement for Hyper-V capability.

Comment: Your mainboard has to support Hyper-V ;-)

Comment: @Thomas I have Accer Aspire E 15 PC can I run on it?

Comment: You need Windows 8.x Pro (not standard), and a CPU that supports SLAT (and also have it enabled in the BIOS). You should be able to see it n add/remove components if your PC supports it.